# Reauthorize for Session.NewPermissionsRequest on android without facebook app

Tags: android, facebook

Im using the new facebook SDK (3) for android.
When im trying to get new permissions of publish by

```
Session.NewPermissionsRequest
```

the app demand to login in the webview again for somereason.

thanks